# Putting an image as a frame around an iframe?

Tags: css, iframe

I have a site I'm trying to display in a mobile format, but on a wide screen. I'm convinced the iframe is the way to go.

I'm trying to load the iframe inside an image of an iPhone. You can see an example [here](http://webfro.gs/south/tour/iframe_test.html).

Once you see it, you should be able to tell what I'm trying to do.

**I've got this CSS down to allow for the iframe to be displayed inside the iPhones screen...**

```
/*iframe Overlay*/
#over{
    position: absolute;
    top: 84px;
    left: 133px;
    width: 485px;
    height: 320px;
}

iframe{
    width: 100%;
    height: 550px;
    background-image: url(../images/iphone5_hollow_750x380.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

**And here's the associated HTML...**

```
   <div id="over"><iframe src="http://webfro.gs/south/tour"></iframe></div>
        <iframe src="http://www.google.com">
            You don't have iframe support, unfortunately
        </iframe>
    </div>
```

**Questions...**

I have no idea why, but I'm being forced to keep that iframe snippet with the google website in there. If I take that out, then the phone image doesn't display.

Why is that?

Is this the best way to do this? Something easier out there?

Getting this to display in IE8 seems to be a whole other nightmare.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You should first fix your HTML - you have mis-matched DIV tags. Each opening div-tag requires a closing-tag, and they cannot overlap.

Comment: Okay. I cleaned up the <div> tags. I'm still getting the same issues though...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok first we need to change the html a little. All you need is:

```
<div id="over">
    <iframe src="http://webfro.gs/south/tour"></iframe>
</div>
```

Then for the CSS:

```
#over {
    background-image: url("../images/iphone5_hollow_750x380.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 380px;
    width: 750px;
    margin: 0 auto 30px;
    position: relative;
}

iframe {
    height: 321px;
    width: 483px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 28px;
    left: 134px;
}
```

Comment: Ok. It would appear I had some things backwards. Thanks TW!

Comment: Any ideas on how to make this viewable in IE8? When I pull it up there, the iframe is stretched, and the pic of the phone doesn't even show. Thoughts?

Comment: It looks fine to me in IE8. Have you refreshed?

Comment: I did refresh. It's just very buggy. I keep having to click 'Compatibility View' if I want to see it properly. IE8 is our corporate browser. I already have the site calling  "Respond.min.js" to allow IE8 to render media queries, but it's not helping me to debug the issues with IE8...

Comment: I'm afraid you'll need to ask a new question. I've looked at it in a native IE8 browser and the iPhone image and iframe placement looks perfect. The issue I think you are referring to is the actual iframe content not responding correctly. I looked at the site in full screen and the issue happens there too.