# Is there any way to write code or use <iframe> tag to display service related content in .JPEG / .PNG images

Tags: html

When the end user is viewing downloaded images from web, at that point, the client wants to display his service related information in bottom of the image (if internet connection is available). Is it there any way to display content in .JPEG / PNG images when the end user opens it from his machine.

Comment: What service related information? Do you have any code? What exactly is your desired output, maybe you could attach a picture that you make using an image editing program or software like Paint or Photoshop, seeing as how you are asking some type of output involving images? Could you also clarify your question as it seems a bit broad? Here is a link on how to properly structure a question on stack: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This is new requirement for me, i am also confused about this, But we are checking can we able to put <ifrme> tag or any html code to display service content in some part of .JPEG / .PNG image.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you're asking... But here is a link to what I understand your question is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17497613/putting-an-image-as-a-frame-around-an-iframe You cannot put an iframe inside an image however you can make it appear to be inside an image by setting the iframe's width and height properties and then placing it relative to the parent container, and placing the image inside that container as well. Something like this: `<div class="parent"><img src="myImage.jpg"/><iframe src="something.com"></iframe></div>`

Comment: Thanks for your replay Wheels, But i am expecting is it possible to show subset of service related information in .JPEG / .PNG image, When it open from machine. is there any possible way to achieve this requirement.

Comment: You say when it's opened from machine, are you talking about a file from the user's computer, or are you talking about some sort of interaction with the website, such as uploading an image?

Comment: File open from computer / any mobile device

Answer (score 0):

If the image is downloaded on to the users computer, then to make this possible you would need a program to track and modify the images on the computer. If they are on the web there are many server side languages which can do this. You can have dynamic images presented to the user, or set a new image to be created with the current message you'd like to display.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Is it possible to show service related info in JPEG /PNG images without any program in computer.